# Horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear in DIV allthough overflow set to auto

Tags: css, asp.net, scrollbar

I have a Div with an image that changes its size on click events. The div is supposed to react, displaying the scrollbars when necessary.

```
   <div id="DisplayGraph" runat="server">
   <asp:image runat="server" id="Graph" CssClass="Graph"/>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
#DisplayGraph {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
transform-origin: left top;
position:fixed;
top: 37px;
left:0px;
overflow:auto;
}

.Graph {
vertical-align: top;
text-align:left;
}
```

ONLY the vertical scrollbar is displayed. If I remove the overflow tag from CSS then the vertical scrollbar disappears - this to prove that CSS is actually working.

So why isn't the horizontal bar showing up?

Comment: Do you have any other CSS that might be affecting those elements?

Comment: No, no other CSS defined in that document. It's loaded within a frame (yes, I'm still using frames) - if this might have an impact.

Comment: Is it possible that the horizontal scrollbar is being cut off/hidden by the frame? Try decreasing the height of `#DisplayGraph`

Comment: I think you are right. This behavior seems to be related to the use of the frameset which is not supported anymore. If called seperately the page loaded in that frame would display the horizontal scrollbar. As you predicted decreasing the height does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the #DisplayGraph is 100% of the parent element, but then you apply a top offset of 37px to a fixed element, meaning relative to the viewport. So the last 37px of the element will be hidden.

You just need to subtract the top offset from the height of your container.

```
#DisplayGraph {
height: calc(100% - 37px);
width: 100%;
transform-origin: left top;
position:fixed;
top: 37px;
left:0px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: The hiding occurs probably because I'm using the not-anymore-supported frameset. Checking your theory I first removed the top offset of 37px to see the impact and actually nothing changed. Then reducing the height the horizonal scrollbar really popped up. Extremely happy with the syntax of your formula, which is exactly what solved this problem.